# How to compute wall heat flux q with just wall temperature

Tags: heat-transfer, cooling, cfd

[image]I am doing some simulation for natural circulation loop and have a heat rate q in the heating leg and a fixed temperature for the cooling leg. I know the heat rate for the heating section (128 W) and I know the fixed temperature for the cooler (9.87 °C). The issue that I am facing is, how to computed wall heat flux for the cooler from the fixed temperature.

I do not know the thickness of the wall or the initial temperature for $\Delta T$ for the cooler. the usual equation for heat flux is $q = h \cdot \Delta T$ or $q = -k \frac{\Delta T }{dx}$ the heat transfer coefficient is also unknown.

can someone help with this please.

I am trying to mimic the experiment in this article using 1-d full conservation equations https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0017931097000070

Comment: Please include a drawing of your simulation geometry.

Comment: unless the system is heating up forever, the heat out must equal the heat in

Comment: @TigerGuy you seem to not understand what I meant. I added the natural circulation  loop schematic for you. cooling and heating do not necessarily equal each other so the principle you mentioned is not what I am talking about.

Comment: @Algo I added the schematic as you requested and this is the article I would like to mimic the loop in the article experiment in 1-d unsteady state with full conservation equations. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0017931097000070

Comment: @yamifm0f If I am reading the image correctly heat enters the system at the bottom left hand side at a rate $q_h$ and exits on the top left side, in what looks like a counterflow heat exchanger?

Comment: if heating and cooling are not equal, the system will heat up or cool down until they are or until it melts or freezes

Comment: @NMech the flow is clockwise flow the heat exchanger here is cooled by a cooler liquid but the average cooler temperature is 9.87 C so I just need to figure out an equivalent heat flux for that. The wall thickness or velocity of the cooling liquid flow was bot given in the article.

Comment: @Tiger-guy natural circulation my friend will keep heating and cooling the flow in the loop forever. Think of the heating section as a nuclear rod and the cooler as a heat exchanger aiming to cool down the rod

Comment: And thus the steady state heat out must equal the heat in.

Comment: @Tiger-guy heating part and heat exchanger are not equal.

Comment: @Tiger-guy they can be equal but in this experiment equal heat flux was not used.

Comment: @yamifm0f TigerGuy is trying to explain exactly the same principle I tried to explain (and obviously failed). Probably there is something that we do not describe in the same terms or we just don't understand.  For example :"*The flow is clockwise flow the heat exchanger here is cooled by a cooler liquid but the average cooler temperature is 9.87 C so I just need to figure out an equivalent heat flux for that.*". To me the word *that* is not clear if that it refers to the heat exchanger walls. If that is the case you should - IMHO - edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @yamifm0f and maybe someone with better communication skills than myself might be able to explain to you that the distribution of temperatures in a heat exchanger is seldom linear, thus quoting the average value is not a good value for calculating the heat transfer.

Comment: If the system is not steady state then there is more information we need, like the starting temp of the fluid, the entry and exit temps of cooling, flow rates for both primary and cooling fluids. The only way for heat out to not equal heat in is for the system to be heating up or cooling down.  With the data given, the best assumption is steady state, for which heat out must equal heat in.  So the heat out through the cooling system needs to equal 128W.

Comment: @NMech I see. I thought that by simply saying natural circulation one would understand what I was speaking of. The “flow is clockwise” meant for your comment “counterflow” meaning that your comment was false because the heating part and cooling part creates a density gradient and flow is driven by buoyancy force. If I was to setup my own values I would not use an average temperature for the cooler I would use a heat flux. You are correct that the temperature in the cooler is linear but the article failed to give the initial temperature of the cooler, the flow velocity of the cooler

Comment: @NMech and failed to give wall thickness. Although this is a famous article that was cited by many.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking just for heat flux (aka  heat flux density, heat-flow density or heat flow rate intensity)  and you know that the heat rate is 128 W, then the heat flux is just:

$$\phi_q = \frac{\dot{q}}{A}$$

where:

- $\phi_q$ is the heat flux
- $\dot{q}$: the heat rate in W
- ${A}$ the surface area.

Comment: yeah that would be good if I knew the heat rate W. I know the heat rate for the heating leg but I only know the cooling temperature for the cooler. in the equation that you mentioned only area is known.

Comment: if the cool surface keeps a constant temperature 9.87 C, then the $\Delta T$ (which will be different for convection and conductive) will adjust itself so that it accommodates heat rate of 128W. Unless, I am not understanding something in your setup and your terms "cooling leg" and "heating leg".

Comment: so a natural circulation system contains one heating leg where you apply a heat flux or a heat rate and parallel to that leg or pipe if you will you have a cooling system (heat exchanger) this can be with a constant temperature where it is lower than the temperature in the heating section or a negative heat flux (-128 W). https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0017931097000070 I am trying to mimic this article experiment in 1-d unsteady state with full conservation equations.

Answer (score 0):

The paper you linked states clearly that this is a steady state investigation of natural circulation of water near density extremes (density inversion), so as @Tiger Guy said in the comments, the heat in (heater) must equal the heat out (cooler).